# Alcohol consumption and reaction time

Tags: data-request, medical, biology

Anybody have a source for experimental data on alcohol consumption and reaction time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cdc is probably your best bet. start here:
http://www.cdc.gov/alcohol/fact-sheets/alcohol-use.htm